# Joining two sentences into a compound predicate sentence using conjunction "and"

Tags: conjunctions, conjunction-reduction, coordinating-conjunctions

Which is the correct way to join the sentences and make a compound predicate sentence?

The boys are playing football. They are enjoying themselves.

1. The boys are playing football and enjoying themselves.

Or

2. The boys are playing football and are enjoying themselves.

Answer (score 5):

Either 1 or 2 is okay, and they mean the same.  Starting from "The boys are playing football and the boys are enjoying themselves", you can conjoin two of the constituents that differ if everything else in the two original conjuncts is the same (including the reference of "the boys").  The eligible pairs are the VPs "are playing football" and "are enjoying themselves", and the inner VPs "playing football" and "enjoying themselves".  The rule involved is called conjunction-reduction (which I have seen referred to here quite a few times).

Comment: Although both may be grammatical, I think the first one is more common. We generally avoid repeating common phrases when conjoing clauses.

Comment: Who's "we"? ...

Comment: Most native English speakers, in my experience.